# Переключение камер WebRTC, если камер больше двух

Tags: android, webrtc

На экране приложения есть два SurfaceViewRenderer, один выводит трансляцию с камеры на вашем устройстве, а второй трансляцию с камеры того с кем вы общаетесь. Вы можете переключать камеры, фронтальная и задняя.

Так как Samsung S9 имеет две фронтальные камеры, то метод
`сameraVideoCapturer.switchCamera(null)` переключает камеры следующим образом: 
фронтальная-фронтальная-задняя. А нужно: фронтальная-задняя.

Получалось пропускать, задавая id камеры и создавая новый videoTrack

```
videoCapturer = enumerator.createCapturer(idCamera, null)
val videoSource = factory.createVideoSource(videoCapturer)
val videoTrack = factory.createVideoTrack(videoTrackId, videoSource)
```

При этом пробовал разные комбинации остановки стримов и вызова `dispose` у все, чего только можно. Самое лучшее чего удалось достичь, это ,у меня камеры переключались хорошо, моя трансляция и трансляция собеседника воспроизводились нормально. Но у собеседника моя трансляция зависала.

Что нужно сделать, что бы переключение было только между одной фронтальной и одной задней камер или есть способ, при котором трансляция не зависает?

Answer (score 0):

Официальное [решение](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=11261&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Stars%20M%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified).

До этого было возможно только переключать камеры методом
`switchCamera(CameraSwitchHandler switchEventsHandler)`

Появится новый метод который позволит выбирать камеру
`switchCamera(CameraSwitchHandler switchEventsHandler, String cameraName)`

Осталось дождаться.